# Writing a product as a factorial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, factorial, frobenius-method

So I'm solving a differential equation with the Frobenius method but I'm stuck with the coefficients. I get that 
$a_n = \frac{(-2)^na_0}{n!(3n+1)(3n-2)(3n-5)...1}$ but I can't figure out how to write $(3n+1)(3n-2)(3n-5)...1$ as a factorial.

Comment: It isn't a factorial. You can express it via the gamma function though.

Comment: You can, although, express it as $(3n+1)!^{(3)}$ using multifactorial notation.

Comment: See [multifactorial on mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html) and [A007661 on oeis](http://oeis.org/A007661)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(3n+1)(3n-2)(3n-5)...(4)(1)=\prod_{k=0}^n(3k+1)=3^n\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac43)}{\Gamma(\frac43)}$$
$$a_n = \frac{(-2)^na_0}{n!(3n+1)(3n-2)(3n-5)...1}=\frac{(-2)^na_0}{n!3^n\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac43)}{\Gamma(\frac43)}}=\frac{(-\frac23)^n\Gamma(\frac43)a_0}{n!\Gamma(n+\frac43)}$$
I suppose that the function you are looking for is $\quad y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$
$$y(x) = a_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\Gamma(\frac43)}{n!\Gamma\big(n+\frac43\big)}\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)^n= a_0\:\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac43\right)J_{1/3}\left((\frac{2x}{3})^{1/2}\right)}{(\frac{2x}{3})^{1/6}}$$
$J\:$ is a Bessel function of first kind.